# Migrating from IBM MQ to RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Can we migrate from IBM MQ to Rabbit MQ ? Is this possible?
Are there any dependencies.What are the factors that we need to look at.

Answer (score 1):

That's like asking can you migrate from Java to c++. Both things do the same thing but are different by structure (at least).

You can do it of course, but I wouldn't call it migrating, but setting up new. They are both message queue brokers and you could keep some concepts (architecturally looking) but the whole "physical" infrastructure would needed to be set up from scratch.

Comment: Okay.Thanks.
Yeah,I know that the question was not framed properly:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-look at the current messaging design pattern and re-design it for RabbitMQ. And design the roll-out strategy. Secondly all the producers and consumers need to be re-written. You need to take into consideration how much effort the producer and consumer applications need to migrate to the new messaging system and secondly Messaging Format also slightly different here in RabbitMQ. So you need to take various aspect into consideration before migrating.